# How can I get information which is only related to current local working branch?

Tags: git, version-control

My final aim is to update my local working branch fast.

In the remote, there is a huge database contains many branches and tags and so on.
Once I sync(or clone) a remote repository into my local repository,
When I do 'repo forall -c 'git pull' to get the latest information, all information of all git projects is retrieved so it takes too long time.

For example, my_local_working_branch_1 corresponds to remote/working_branch_1.
In my case, there are about 300 git projects for my_local_working_branch_1

```
$ git branch
my_local_working_branch_1

$ repo forall -c 'git pull'
remote : couting objects: ...
remote : Compressing object: ...
remote : Total ...
From ssh://......
*[new branch] working_branch_2
*[new branch] working_branch_3
*[new tag]    ...
*[new tag]    ...
```

To save time, I want to update ONLY my_local_working_branch, actually 300 git projects of it, from remote/working_branch.

Can I use git fetch or git pull?
Please give detailed description.

If you need more information to understand it completely, please let me know that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can either `pull` the branch (what you're doing actually), or `fetch` + `rebase` it.

```
git pull <remote> <branch>

# the same as 

git fetch <remote> <branch>
git merge <remote>/<branch> <local_branch>
```

Or:

```
git fetch <remote> <branch>
git rebase <remote>/<branch> <local_branch>
```

I let you try both cases and see which one suits you.

Comment: Here is my current description about GIT branch & config.

    $ git branch
    my_local_working_branch_1

    $ git config -l
    remote.mps-git.url=ssh://....
    remote.mps-git.review=....
    remote.mps-git.projectname=....
    remote.mps-git.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/mps-git/*
    branch.my_local_working_branch_1.remote=mps-git
    branch.my_local_working_branch_1.merge=refs/head/working_branch_1


According to your answer, which one is correct?

    $ git pull mps-git my_local_working_branch_1

or

    $ git pull working_branch_1 my_local_working_branch_1


Thanks in advance.

Comment: `git pull mps working_branch_1`. You need to be on the `my_local_working_branch_1` branch. If you aren't, move to it first: `git co my_local_working_branch_1`.